# How to Apply HTML CSS desiging to TreeView Control

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I have a dynamically created tree view control in ASP.NET. I want to format that treeview control and want to apply some designing. I have found this on on stackoverflow but I don't know whether I can apply to my dynamically created Treeview control or not?

Here is the link that I found on stackoverflow for tree view

https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/

and here is my code

```
                <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowLines="true">
                </asp:TreeView>
```

Please let me know how to apply this styling to dynamically added treeview control.

Answer (score 2):

Check This ! this will help You

```css
 .treeNode
        {
            transition: all .3s;
            padding: 12px 5px;
            text-align: center;
            /*width: 100%;*/
            margin: 0;
            min-width: 250px !important;
            border: 2px solid #8e44ad;
            text-decoration:none !important;
            color:black;
            /*color:blue;
            font:14px Arial, Sans-Serif;*/
        }
     .rootNode
        {
            font-size:18px;
            /*width:100%;*/
            border-bottom:Solid 1px black;
            color:#337ab7;
        }
     .leafNode {
            border: Dotted 2px black;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
     .selectNode 
   {
        background-color:Black;
        border:Dotted 2px black;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#fff;
    }
```

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvw_Category"  runat="server" NodeStyle-CssClass="treeNode"
    RootNodeStyle-CssClass="rootNode"
    LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="leafNode" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="selectNode" 
                 OnTreeNodeCheckChanged  ="tvw_Category_TreeNodeCheckChanged"  ExpandDepth="1"  Font-Size="Small">
                        </asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASP:TreeView's CSSClass property to apply CSS to the TreeView Control

Comment: can I apply a similar properties as shown in the link?